# How to re-format a date-time string in nxlog or how to set up date-time format for python logging file

Tags: python, logging, timestamp, nxlog

Whilst it's a two question post, the answer to either one will fix my single problem, so I only need a response to one of the two questions.

I'm using an app called [dynamic-dynamodb](http://dynamic-dynamodb.readthedocs.org) do scale our dynamo tables.

The next thing is to get the logs from that into logstash via nxlog, I've done that as well.

The problem is that the date-time format is slightly wrong, it's

`2015-02-24 14:55:39,777`

instead of (note the `T` and the `.`):

`2015-02-24T14:55:39.777`

Frankly speaking, the [documentation](http://dynamic-dynamodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_configuration.html#example-logging-conf) on how to configure the logging output is kind of.. well it's rubbish.

I was able to work out how to format it as json but I can't work out how to change the date-time format as it stands.

Here's my format (the format string is stored as a heredoc in a hash and then written to the conf as a template in chef):

```
{
    "EventReceivedTime": "%(asctime)s",
    "name":  "%(name)s",
    "level": "%(levelname)s",
    "message": "%(message)s",
    "type":"dynamic-dynamodb",
    "hostname": "#{node['hostname']}",
    "enviroment" : "#{node.chef_environment}",
    "node_name" : "#{app_name}",
    "ipaddress" : "#{node['ipaddress']}"
}
```

So, since I can't work out how to change the format I thought I'd re-format the date-time string via nxlog (which reads the log in as json) before I push to logstash but I've looked and well, I can't seem to find how to do that either.

So, any help to answer either of the problems would be fantastic.

1) How to re-format the time directly in the logger format

or

2)How to re-format the date-time in nxlog before I push to logstash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work out how to change the date-time format that the logger outputs as.
I added to the logfile config

```
datefmt=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
```

and changed the formatter to:

```
"
{
    'EventReceivedTime': '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d',
    'name':  '%(name)s',
    'level': '%(levelname)s',
    'message': '%(message)s',
    'type':'dynamic-dynamodb',
    'hostname': '#{node['hostname']}',
    'enviroment' : '#{node.chef_environment}',
    'node_name' : '#{app_name}',
    'ipaddress' : '#{node['ipaddress']}'
}
".gsub('\'','"')#<-- this is so I can juse use ' rather than having to \"
```

The reason for the change from heredoc to multiline string was because I couldn't add a second element to the hash properly, this was the only way.

The reason for gsub was because It was easier to gsub every `'` for `"` then having to escape every `"` with `\"`.

I used information from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects) to realise that I could just add `datefmt` to the log file and it would change the datetime template. 
Specifically it was the presence of `datefmt` within both the yaml format and the json format that made me realise I could just do the same for the logger config.